# multiple projects using same code for ci/cd deployment

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

We are using Gitlab for ci/cd deployment. It has variables and one tracker which is read and deployed when we execute pipeline.
We have new project coming where we need kind of ci/cd to be setup.

I do not want to duplicate the deployment code. Is there any way in gitlab where in I have single place of ci/cd code. 2 projects just inherit all the code from parent. in child projects we can maintain their specific variables and tracker which will be used for deployment.

Example: Parent P repo should have all the deployment code.
Child c1 and c2 inherit parent code and their variables/files.

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward approach is to use the [`include:` keyword](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#include) to include configurations from other projects. That way you don't have to repeat the same CI definitions in different projects, but you can include common configuration files and add/override definitions in the project `.gitlab-ci.yml`.

Another approach would be to use the [custom CI configuration file setting](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/settings.html#specify-a-custom-cicd-configuration-file) to specify the CI configuration file that exists in a central project. Variables can still be set independently in the settings of each project, but each project won't even need its own `.gitlab-ci.yml` file.

If you need actual *code* or other resources other than the YAML definitions from other projects, you need to have a script step that clones the code from the other project(s) as part of the job. Alternatively, you can include any necessary code in the `image:` used for the job (if using docker-based executors).